# Rcpp: cannot return object created in loop

Tags: c++, rcpp

I think I am missing something rather fundamental, but I don't know what:

```
    #include <Rcpp.h>
    using namespace Rcpp;
    // [[Rcpp::export]]

    NumericMatrix test(NumericVector x) {

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
              NumericMatrix n_m1(4,5);
    }
    return n_m1;
    }
```

This gives me the errors:

Line 17 'n_m1' was not declared in this scope

Line 19 control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

The first error is clearly nonsense. It has  to do with the loop, because it works perfectly fine if I remove it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of this variable(`n_m1`):

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
              NumericMatrix n_m1(4,5);
}
```

is *the loop*. So of course outside the loop you can't use it.
Neither return it.

To extend the scope define at method level:

```
NumericMatrix test(NumericVector x) {
    NumericMatrix n_m1(4,5);

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
      // you can use it here now
    }

    return n_m1; // also here
    }
```

The way I defined the variable above now it has function scope - e.g., you can only use it inside the function. If you want to further extend the scope, maybe you can consider global variables? You can read more on that topic if interested, e.g., [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. How can I extend the scope of the variable to the "whole" environment?